# Java ArrayList Number Classifier not spacing correctly

Tags: java, arraylist

Ok, so I recently tried to create a java program in eclipse that basically takes an infinite amount of numbers that are 1-100, and stores them in an arraylist. Once this is done, it is supposed to print them out in a horizontal bar graph.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
/*
 * 1-10
 * 11-20
 * 21-30
 * 31-40
 * 41-50
 * 51-60
 * 61-70
 * 71-80
 * 81-90
 * 91-100
 * 
 * Created by Peter browning, PBdeveloping, 2015
 */
public class Asterisks {

public static ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter some numbers, 1-100, 0 to stop.");
    int input = reader.nextInt();
    while (input != 0)
    {
        if ((input >= 1) && (input <= 100))
        {
        array.add(input);
        input = reader.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Number must be 1-100");
            input = reader.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        int firstNumber = ((i - 1) * 10) + 1;
        int secondNumber = (i * 10);
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + "       |" );
        for (int nInsideArray : array)
        {
            if ((nInsideArray >= firstNumber) && (nInsideArray <=                 secondNumber))
            {
                count++;

            }
            }
        for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)

            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();

    }


    }


}
```

So the problem that I am having is, whenever I keep on trying to run this program, (lets use the user input "1", "21",  then "0" as an example, it should print out:

```
1-10     | *

11-20    |

21-30    | *

31-40    |

41-50    |

51-60    |

61-70    |

71-80    |

81-90    |

91-100    |
```

but instead it prints out....

```
1 - 10       |
*
11 - 20       |

21 - 30       |
*
31 - 40       |

41 - 50       |

51 - 60       |

61 - 70       |

71 - 80       |

81 - 90       |

91 - 100       |
```

Note: the asterisks are not beside the |'s for some reason, any help would be appreciated. Also if you have a more efficient way to code something like this, I would love to hear your input. I usually learn alot on this website, so please help me with my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are printing the pipe with a `println()`. Change that to `print()`. When you are done printing asterisks do a `println` for a new line.

Comment: Any chance you could explain how this works? I know there are multiple websites that explain basic java concepts, but I don't understand most people's robotic thoughts. My issue is when it states that whenever x (or just a placeholder variable) is less than count (or the number of numbers that fit into a specific category), it prints an asterisk. But shouldn't it print another line aswell? So basically I don't understand why  all the asterisks can be side-by-side, when if an asterisk is being printed, a new line must also be printed. Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Println is the exact same as print, it just adds a new line character (\n or \r\n). Anything printed after the new line character gets put on a new line. Since you want the asterisk to be on the same line, don't print a new line character, only print the text. Than after the asterisk print a new line character to create a new line

Comment: @Peter_Browning println prints a line with a character return "\n", thus creating a new line

Comment: Just now realizing this, I didn't completely understand  how the whole for loop thing worked when there aren't any brackets present, but whenever you have a for loop, it should be conventionally `for (initialize;condition; move on) {  //stuff}` but when I did this, I didnt put a bracket directly after the 3 parameters. What does this change?

Comment: There should be no problem as long as the brackets are after the three parameters. Of course there's still the issue of readability.